# dd: warning: partial read (2147479552 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, ssd, swap, dd

I am trying to increase the swap memory size to 32GB. I am having 16GB of RAM and 256GB of SSD. I want to increase the swap memory size and using [this](https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/) tutorial to increase the swap memory. I am trying to create 8 blocks each of 4GB using this command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=4G count=8
```

and received this warning

> dd: warning: partial read (2147479552 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock

this was the output after the process was completed.

```
dd: warning: partial read (2147479552 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock
0+8 records in
0+8 records out
17179836416 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 221.605 s, 77.5 MB/s
```

**My question**
Is it okay to create 8 blocks each of 4GB, as I am not aware of this? If not, what pattern should I follow? Why does that warning appear?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall util-linux
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
```

Comment: what will this do?

Comment: @JAMSHAID: Replace the dd command in the tutorial to create a 4 G swap file, upgrade the system, install or reinstall the fallocate command, and create the swap file.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package fallocate

Comment: when running sudo apt install --reinstall fallocate

Comment: @JAMSHAID: Fallocate command, is part of util-linux, fixed.

Comment: will the rest of the tutorial work fine?

Comment: @JAMSHAID: Yes . dd  command, is a cranky tool, which is hard to use correctly.

Comment: @kayodek it has created 16GB swap whereas i was expecting 32gb. is there something wrong that was done by me?